# Data from $resource not synchronized to call from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm able to get the print the array returned inside vm.getProduct() in the controller. But this not available in HTML.

Resource:

```
                var DataProvider = function ($resource) {
                    return $resource('', {}, {

                        getProductTypeAhead: {
                            method: 'GET',
                            isArray: true,
                            url: '/productinterface?typeahead=:typeAhead',
                            params: {typeAhead: '@typeAhead'}
                        }
                    });
                };

                module.exports = ['$resource', DataProvider];
```

Service:

```
        var DataService = function (DataProvider, $scope) {
            this.getProductTypeAhead = function (typeAhead, callback) {
                DataProvider.getProductTypeAhead({typeAhead: typeAhead},
                    function (data) {
                        callback(data);
                    }, function (data) {
                        // NOTIFY THE USER THAT THE REQUEST FAILED
                        callback(null);
                    });
            };
        };

        module.exports = ['DataProvider', DataService];
```

Controller:

```
    vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
        return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue, function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            return cleanResponse(response);
        });
    };


    function cleanResponse(response) {
        return JSON.parse(global.angular.toJson(response));
    }
```

HTML:

```
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="product"
            typeahead-min-length="3"
            typeahead="product as product.legalName for product in vm.getProduct($viewValue)"
            typeahead-template-url="app/main/templates/typeahead-ProductInterface-Template.html"
            ng-model="vm.trade.PRODUCT_NAME">
```

However, if I go for $http.get() approach, I'm able to see the array in HTML.

```
                vm.getProduct1 = function ($viewValue) {
                return $http.get('/productinterface?typeahead=' + $viewValue).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return response.data;
                });
            };
```

I checked for the posts to synchronize $resource calls. No luck in that front.
Any pointers on this issue will be much appreciated.

TIA,
Bhushan

Comment: What does it log to the console? Is the **response** in the right format? What is the data look like after `cleanResponse(response);`?

Comment: cleanResponse removes $promise and $response
[w, w, w, w, $promise: o, $resolved: true]
becomes
[object,object,object,object]

Comment: But you know that is the idea of using '$resource'. Probably you should better stay with `$http' then.

Comment: I want to trim this only when I return the value to HTML. Implementation is to show all the array contents in a drop down.

Comment: Ok, that is up to you, but this doesn't make any sense to me. You just show `product.legalName` to the user. He won't see any private (`$`) properties or functions of the `$resource` instance.

Comment: true.. cleanResponse is something which we use in other places in our project.. this something which is required for this like you mentioned, but the actual issue of passing this array information to HTML is still not solved! :(

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna use `$resource` with `typeahead` you can't use the normal callbacks. You need to return a promise.

Return a promise of a `$resource` request:

```
vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
    return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue, function (response) { 
        return response;
    }).$promise;
};
```

Return a promise of a `$resource` request with callback;

```
vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
    return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue)
         .$promise.then(function(response) {
              return doSomethingWith(response);
         });
    });
};
```

See [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/phbdTXEiwshuPPo6ANdT?p=preview) - Asynchronous results

Comment: vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
    return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue)
      .$promise.then(function(response) {
        return doSomethingWith(response);
      });
    });
   };

Cannot call this because service expects callback

Comment: After looking deeper into the problem. You still can use the normal callbacks - but you need to return the `$promise` to make the `typeahead` work.

Comment: I'm lost with the implementation.  Can you please give me an implementation where I can successfully pass the array to HTML?

Answer (score -1):

You are returning a promise not the value. That is vm.getProduct is a funciton that returns a promise not data.

```
vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
    return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        return cleanResponse(response);
    });
};


function cleanResponse(response) {
    return JSON.parse(global.angular.toJson(response));
}
```

You should set it to any vm property like this

```
vm.getProduct = function ($viewValue) {
    return DataService.getProductTypeAhead($viewValue, function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        vm.myProperty = cleanResponse(response);
        return cleanResponse(response);
    });
};
```

Comment: I guess it is the idea to return a promise for this [typeahead](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead) impementation. What is `vm.myProperty = cleanResponse(response);` good for?